# Location of Raftel

Tags: one-piece

In the Zou arc, it was revealed that Raftel is located at the intersection of the four locations written on the four road poneglyphs. But if we think about it, we can tell the location of Raftel with just two road poneglyphs, as it should be on the mid point of the two islands if we draw a line. Is that correct?

I am currently on the Whole Cake Island arc, so I don't know if anything is revealed in the later arcs.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe the arcs after Whole Cake Island have added anything new to this, but there are some issues with your assumptions. This is what the wiki on [Chapter 818](https://onepiece.fandom.com/wiki/Chapter_818) states about the Road Poneglyphs (emphasis mine):

> The Straw Hats are astonished that this poneglyph can lead them to Laugh Tale, but Inuarashi backtracks, revealing that there are four Road Poneglyphs. He states that each poneglyph does not lead to Laugh Tale, but rather to an island surrounding it. **When all four islands are found and linked**, the way to Laugh Tale will be shown.

The way this is phrased, it might be important to visit all islands and perform some action there to "link" them in order to reach Laugh Tale. The One Piece world does have a lot of unusual geography and erratic weather phenomenon, so extrapolating the location might not be a valid option.

Geometrically, we know this:

> Each Road Poneglyph gives a location, and the four locations create a quadrangle with Laugh Tale in the intersection of the diagonals.

While the diagonals in a parallelogram (like squares and rectangles) will definitely intersect at their midpoints, it is possible to have quadrilateral shapes where diagonals intersect at some different ratio (for example, a kite-like shape or an irregular shape).

Additionally, even if the diagonals meet at their midpoint, unless you find poneglyphs that give you two locations diagonally opposite to each other, you'd end up going to the midpoint of an edge, which is the wrong location.

Comment: A quirk to the last point, without all 4 poneglyphs the odds are against guessing the location. If you did wind up with a random pair of poneglyphs the odds are against them being opposite each other. In any 4 sided polygon each point has 1 point diagonal to it but 2 points adjacent to it so you're 1/3 to have a diagonal rather than an edge. Similarly for 3 poneglyphs, you know you must have 1 diagonal among the points but you can't know which pair and you have 3 possible pairings and only 1 is correct so you're again 1/3 to figure out which is the diagonal

Answer (score 1):

[image]

These 4 crosses represent the location given by each road poneglyphs, so if you have only two road poneglyphs then you can not find intersection of those two lines formed by four road poneglyphs, and also you have no way of knowing which two road poneglyphs you have so you can not travel on that whole line from one road poneglyph location to other although if you try that and are lucky enough to have two right road poneglyphs then you may find Raftel (Although it's actually Laugh Tale).